# Sqlite - BETWEEN and GREATER THAN (<) is always return 0 in Cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, between

I am trying to keep my SELECT Query in a cursor in Android
I use this query :

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_main_words WHERE word_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500 ORDER BY word_eng",null)
```

and cursor.getCount() returned 0! 
it is same for greather than (<) Queries !
while it shouldn't be :(
Because I have 15000 rows in my table in myDb with word_id from 1 to 15000

NOTE: the problem is not from database because I can return the true value from some queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_main_words WHERE word_id > 0 ORDER BY word_eng
```

IMPORTANT: these queries are executed without any problem in some SQLite software like SQLite Expert!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that your issue is with the query, it works fine using :-

```
public class SO51108624DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "worddb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_MAIN_WORDS = "tbl_main_words";
    public static final String COL_WORDID = "word_id";
    public static final String COL_WORDENG = "word_eng";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SO51108624DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_MAIN_WORDS + "(" +
                COL_WORDID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_WORDENG + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRow(String word) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_WORDENG,word);
        return mDB.insert(TB_MAIN_WORDS,null,cv);
    }

    public void populateMainWordsTable() {
        mDB.delete(TB_MAIN_WORDS,null,null);
        for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
            addRow("test");
        }
    }

    public int getWordCountBetweenIDs() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_words WHERE word_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500 ORDER BY word_eng";
        Cursor csr = mDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
        int rv = csr.getCount();
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

along with :-

```
    SO51108624DBHelper mDBHlpr = new SO51108624DBHelper(this);
    mDBHlpr.populateMainWordsTable();
    int rowcount = mDBHlpr.getWordCountBetweenIDs();
    Log.d("ROWCOUNT", "Number of rows returned was " + String.valueOf(rowcount));
```

Resulting in :-

**`06-29 22:29:39.193 1452-1452/soanswers.soanswers D/ROWCOUNT: Number of rows returned was 500`**

**As such it is likely that the table itself is empty when you run this. This assuming that you are not missing any errors such as column/table not found.**

You could try using :-

```
Log.d ("ROWCOUNT","Number of rows in tbl_main_words is " + String.valueOf(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(myDb,"tbl_main_words")));
Cursor cursor = myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_main_words WHERE word_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500 ORDER BY word_eng",null)
```

and then checking the log which should then have something like :-

> 06-29 22:36:54.232 1529-1529/soanswers.soanswers D/ROWCOUNT: Number of
>   rows in tbl_main_words is 1000

Comment: i checked my rows when cursur.getCount() called and i realized that  it didn't empty ! when i run query such SELECT * FROM tbl_main_words WHERE word_id > 500 , it works correctly but when i change (>) to (<) it return me 0 while i have lots of rows that have word_id lower than 500 !